# SQL error while using mysql_query() but not in PHPMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I get the following error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1
```

My query is:

```
SELECT * FROM  `history` LIMIT 0 , 30
```

When I run it in PHPMyAdmin it works fine, and the database connection is working.

EDIT: Okay this is solved. My FTP client was saying it was copying the file to the server but when I tried to open the file in cpanle's file manager it was corrupted.

Comment: echo your `$query` from your script. The query you posted here is not the one send per mysql_query()

Comment: The line of code is `$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM history LIMIT 0 , 30") or die(mysql_error());`

Comment: Then that's probably not the line that causes the error, as there is no `1` in it like the mysql error message says.

Comment: @Tom, the error message clearly states there is a number 1 somewhere in your query. It can't be the query you posted.

Comment: It is that line. That is the only SQL query on the page at the moment. When I remove the die() bit from the end of the line the error goes (but obviously the query still doesn't work).

Comment: Post the whole php page please.

Comment: Do you connect to the correct database?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "real" single quotes or leave them out altogether in PHP instead of the "tilted" ones that PhpMyAdmin gives you.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM history LIMIT 0, 30";
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you type your own ', if you copy the query from phpmyadmin the apostrophies are different then the ones you type, like this 'history'